Are there functions analogous to $\zeta(s)$ where some non-trivial zeros are known to be off the critical line?
Are there examples of functions $f(s)$ with functional equation $$f(s)=g(s)\, f(1-s)$$ analogous to the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ with an infinite number of non-trivial zeros which are limited to the critical strip $0<\Re(s)<1$ and the non-trivial zeros are known to be both on and off the critical line $s=\frac{1}{2}+i t$?

To clarify, I'd prefer to stick with a Dirichlet series if possible, but perhaps there are no known Dirichlet series with the properties specified above.

The Davenport-Heilbronn function
$$f(s)=\frac{1}{2} (1-i \alpha)\, L_{5,2}(s)+\frac{1}{2} (1+i \alpha)\, L_{5,4}(s)$$
mentioned in the comments below where
$$\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}-2}{\sqrt{5}-1},$$
$$\chi_{5,2}(n)=(1, i, -i, -1, 0,\, ...),$$
and
$$\chi_{5,4}(n)=(1, -i, i, -1, 0,\, ...)=\chi _{5,2}(n){}^*$$
obeys the functional equation
$$f(s)=2^s\, \pi^{s-1}\, 5^{\frac{1}{2}-s}\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma (1-s)\, f(1-s)$$
and the related function
$$g(s)=\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^{-\frac{s}{2}}\, \Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)\, f(s)$$
obeys the functional equation
$$g(s)=g(1-s).$$

The Davenport-Heilbronn function $f(s)$ has non-trivial zeros both on and off the critical line in the critical strip, but also has has infinitely many zeros for $\Re(s)>1$, so it doesn't fully meet the properties specified above. ZEROS OF THE DAVENPORT-HEILBRONN
COUNTEREXAMPLE gives some computed non-trivial zeros of $f(s)$ off the critical line.

"Non-trivial zeros" is a meaningless term here, technically. I mean, if $h(z)$ is any function whose zeroes are in the strip, then $f(z)=h(z)h(1-z)$ has the property with $g(z)=1,$ but it would depend on what "non-trivial" means.

this is potentially an interesting question but @Thomas says maybe it should be refined a bit to understand exactly what you want - the usual counterexamples to the idea that you can prove RH only from the functional equation do have zeroes with $\Re s >1$

@Conrad The generalized Riemann hypothesis rules out Dirichlet L-functions, but I'm not sure it rules out all Dirichlet series and their associated analytic continuations. Could you give or point me to some of the usual counterexamples?

Davenport Heilbronn type of counterexample - clever linear combinations of $L$ functions to the same modulus which satisfy functional equation - the usual one is for modulus $5$ and you can find a good analysis in the Karatsuba Voronin treatise on RZ; Bagchi proved that any non trivial (meaning at least $2$ distinct such involved) linear combinations of Dirichlet $L$ functions to the same modulus has $1$ as the supremum of the real part of the zeroes in the critical strip and when you choose two conjugate characters you usually can get a clever combination to satisfy a functional equation too

on the other hand if you go away from Dirichlet series you can construct tons of entire functions $f(s)=f(1-s)$ with $f$ having pretty much any set of zeroes you want that is symmetric under $s \to 1-s$ (and under conjugation if you want $f$ to preserve the real line);

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283172/fake-integers-for-which-the-riemann-hypothesis-fails

the post linked above by @i9Fn gives the respective constants but I want to emphasize that this function - the "classical" Davenport-Heilbronn $f(s)=a, L_{5,2}(s)+\bar a, L_{5,4}(s)$ where $a={1 - i\alpha\over 2}, \alpha={\sqrt{10 -2\sqrt{5}} - 2 \over \sqrt{5}-1}$ and its analogs for higher modulus all have (infinitely many) zeroes with $\Re s >1$ in addition to the critical strip zeroes which have supremum of the real part $1$; for $f$ above, it is known that the critical line $\Re s =1/2$ has $\Omega(T)T$ zeroes up to ordinate $T$ where $\Omega(T) \to \infty$

also note that if one wants lots of things like Dirichlet series, functional equation with gamma factors, Euler product (so no non-trivial zeroes outside critical strip - where trivial means that they are forced by the gamma factors like for zeta) and reasonable coefficient bounds, then one gets the Selberg class for which it is conjectured that RH holds so definitely no counterexample is known; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class

@StevenClark, you may want to see this: https://figshare.com/articles/preprint/Untitled_Item/14776146?file=50018199

Dirichlet series associated to half-integral weight forms are very similar to automorphic $L$-functions, except that the Hecke operators don't "see" squarefree indices and the coefficients aren't multiplicative. But they still have functional equations of the form
$$ D(s, f)G(s) = \varepsilon D(1-s, \widetilde{f}) G(1-s).$$
I'll note that in general, the form $\widetilde{f}$ is not just the complex conjugate of the form $f$ in the half-integral weight case --- it can be more complicated.
The Dirichlet series associated to the (unique) half-integral cuspform of weight $9/2$ on $\Gamma_0(4)$ is defined by
$$ g(z) = \eta(2z)^{12} \theta(z)^{-3} $$
for the Dedekind $\eta$ function and the standard Jacobi $\theta$ function. The Dirichlet series $D(s, g)$ satisfies a symmetric functional equation (i.e. $\widetilde{g} = g$). All zeros are to the left of $2$. (Note 100 percent of zeros still lie on the half-line, infinitely many lie off the line, and the zeros are largely mysterious). I've given various talks about this, and have written a series of notes about some of the underlying properties.
Some higher half-integral weight forms seem to give exactly what you want. There is a weight $9/2$ form on $\Gamma_0(12)$ that gives a Dirichlet series with a symmetric functional equation and that seems to have no zeros with real part larger than $0.95$. I couldn't prove that there weren't any zeros in the region of absolute convergence; I think I did show that there weren't any with imaginary part less than $20000$.

When you say "$100$ percent of zeros still lie on the half-line", do you mean
$$\lim\limits_{T\to\infty} \left(\frac{N_{\Re(\rho)\ne\frac{1}{2}}(T)}{N_{\Re(\rho)=\frac{1}{2}}(T)}\right)=0$$
where the numerator and denominator give the counts of non-trivial zeros $\rho$ off and on the critical line with $|\Im(\rho)|<T$? Or should $100$ percent have been $70$ percent mentioned in your slide presentation?

Thanks for sharing your research related to the topic of my question. If I understand your answer, you're not aware of any Dirichlet series which ha been proven to have the properties specified in my question, and also not aware of any proof of the non-existence of such a Dirichlet series.
When counting non-trivial zeros, I assume you treat the related zeros
$$\left{\rho,, 1-\rho,, \rho^,, (1-\rho)^\right}$$
as a count of $1$ instead of $4$.

@StevenClark Your interpretation of $100$ percent is correct. The $70$ percent from the slides is an example of a quantity that we know goes to $0$, but apparently happens very slowly. As far as I can tell, people look only at Selberg class $L$-functions and their linear combinations, presumably because these are the "nicest" things. But these don't have what you're looking for. Concerning your second comment, you're right about my understanding of the literature. And for nontrivial zeros, I think I typically count only zeros with positive real and imaginary parts... but I don't remember.
